Why does conjugation occur in Spyrogyra if it reproduces via isogametes?
I've read in my book(NEET EXPLORER-By Sanjaya Sharma and Sudhakar BanerJee) that Spyrogyra sexually reproduce through conjugation, I have also read many articles which say that it's by isogametes. I thought that in this conjugation hologamete/vegetative cells of opposite strains would merge each other’s cytoplasm and form a diploid zygote from which meiospores would be produced.If isogametes are involved, then why is conjugation necessary? Or does conjugation with isogametes occur?

By far I get the true definition of Isogametes! So, isogametes are of same size, but not merely must be flagellated. They are either motile or non-motile pairs. Then the conjugation here is served for the union of the isogametes. And conjugation may also serve for union of unlike(anisogametes) ones too!
